# Compare two lists and return common entries

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of vendors.  I also have a list of vendor ids.

```
    public List<SAP_Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubcontractVendorIDs { get; set; }
```

I want to return a `List<SAP_Vendor>` of the vendors whose ids are in the SubcontractVendorIDs list.

```
List<SAP_Vendor> SubcontractVendors = Vendors.Select(??).ToList();
```

or

```
List<SAP_Vendor> SubcontractVendors = Vendors.Where(??).ToList();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `Contains()` method in the `Where()` predicate:

```
List<SAP_Vendor> SubcontractVendors = Vendors.Where(v=> SubcontractVendorIDs.Contains(v.VendorID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can perform an [inner join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx):

```
var query = from vendor in Vendors
            join id in SubcontractVendorIDs on vendor.ID equals id
            select vendor;

List<SAP_Vendor> subcontractVendors = query.ToList();
```

Comment: As a one-liner: Vendors.Join(SubcontractVendorIDs, v => v.ID, sv => sv, (v,sv) => v).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
List<SAP_Vendor> SubcontractVendors = Vendors.Where(v => SubcontractVendorIDs.Contains(v.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be using Lists? With LINQ, it's usually best to pass around IEnumerables and only convert to a list when you actually need the data.

As for your actual question, just use the `Contains` method.

```
Vendors.Where(v => SubcontractVendorIDs.Contains(v.Id));
```

Comment: You mean `Where()`, not `Select()` (unless you want a sequence of bools).

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, haven't touched LINQ in a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SAP_Vendor> SubcontractVendors = Vendors.Where(x => SubcontractVendorIDs.Any(y => x == y)).ToList();
```

One of several ways to do this...  Would be faster with a Dictionary or a sorted list